Hay alguna manera para pisar varias entradas del historial al moverme a otra ruta?
Estoy trabajando en un proyecto con NextJs, y me pidieron que busque si hay alguna manera de que al momento de loguearse, todo el historial anterior quede inhabilitado.
Encontré algunos comandos como router.replace() de useRouter pero que solo reemplazan la ruta actual, y lo mismo con window.location.replace().

Según esta respuesta, no es posible borrar el historial. Aunque si en ningún momento cambias la dirección, imagino que el router te podría permitir borrar el "historial" y lo pongo entre comillas porque no es exactamente lo mismo.
